# Intellicode not working properly in Vs code when writing in JSX

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am new to react, and I am implementing a third-party package named **styled-components** to work with the CSS styling in my app

Using the **styled-components** package requires me to write the code that typically includes CSS and javascript(mixed).

For example

```
//para style
const StyledPara = styled.p`
  color: green;

  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
`;

//div style

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 400px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #ccc;
  padding: 40px;
`;

**//Button style**

const ButtonStyle = styled.button`
  padding: 8px;
  font: inherit;
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: ${(props) => (props.colorInfo ? "red" : "green")};
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) =>
      props.colorInfo ? "#ffcccb" : "lightgreen"};
  }
`;
```

I am not able to get the auto-complete suggestions in my VS-code editor whenever I am writing CSS styles such as media-queries etc in JSX.

Is there any way I can solve this issue?  any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components

Comment: Thank you, I've installed the extension as specified in the documentation.